# Comparing more than 2 files in python3

Tags: file, python-3.x

I need to check if more than two files are different, using python3: is there some kind of library for that?

- the files might be relatively big
- I don't care about the differences themselves: knowing they are different is enough (i.e. I'd prefer something that stops as soon as it finds any difference)

filecmp does two files at once, **of course I can do multiple checks, but that's exactly what I'm trying to bypass, if possible**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function takes a list of filenames as a parameter.
Returns True if any two files are different by at least one byte, else False

```
def find_difference(list_of_files, block_size=1000):
    fs=[open(f,'rb') for f in list_of_files]
    while True:
        first=True
        for f in fs:
            if first:
                first=False
                s1=f.read(block_size)
                end=(s1==b'')
                continue
            s2=f.read(block_size)
            if s1!=s2:
                return True
            if end and (s2!=b''):
                end=False
        if end:
            return False
```

Answer (score -3):

use filecmp like this:

```
import filecmp; 
filecmp.cmp(file1,file2)
```

Comment: Please actually read the question before giving a random answer: _filecmp does two files at once, **of course I can do multiple checks, but that's exactly what I'm trying to bypass**, if possible._